# Convex objective but non-convex feasible set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem of the form

$$\min_{\boldsymbol{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}_+}} f(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n)\\
\text{s.t. } \sum_{i=0}^{n} x_i \le C_1\\
g(x_0) \le C_2
$$

the objective $f(x_0,\cdots,x_n)$ is a convex function of the argumetns, however the inequality constraint $g(x_0)$ is not convex, unless I further assume $x_0\le C_3$. All the variables and parameters (given constants $C_1,C_2,C_3$) are positive real numbers. The function $g(x_0)$ is a convex function if $x_0\le C_3$ and is a concave function if $x_0\ge C_3$ and is always increasing. Is there anyway that I can turn this problem into a convex optimization problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Convexity is a property of your problem. If it is non-convex, then non-convex it is. You can derive convex relaxations for your problem but, unless the relaxation gap is shown to be zero, your relaxation will result in lower or upper-bound on your optimal solution. Relaxations are tailored to the problem and since you do not provide any details on the function $g(x_0)$, nothing much can be said. For instance, imposing $x_0\le C_3$ can be seen as a relaxation that will result in an optimal upper-bound for your problem. What is the problem with using this?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The problem is that the bound I specified is actually a random quantity. Here I tried to simplify the problem to ask a general question. The statement $x_0\le C_3$ might not always be true. So nothing can be done about convex structure of problem. I guess I have to take an opportunistic approach then.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Solve numerically your problem? Analytically?

Comment: I am trying to write the dual problem and solve it using KKT, I need to show the duality gap is zero and to show that, a simple way is convexity. However there are random parameters in the equations, I assume we know the random parameters (they are estimated and available), but I can not guarantee some conditions on the random parameters.
I can always solve the problem analytically, but I am trying to solve it analytically or at least get the necessary and sufficient global optimality conditions.

Comment: Betting on the fact that the duality gap will be zero is pretty risky in my opinion. Moreover, it is also quite unlikely there is an analytic solution as only very few problems have one. Finally, necessary and sufficient global optimality conditions may not necessarily exist. What is the structure of the function $g$ here? It will play an important role. Is it a polynomial function? A rational one?